# Setting Search Bar to non-translucent

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, ios7.1

I am using a searchDisplayController in my tableview. I have got the functionality to work, I am now configuring the UI.

I would like the search bar (including the scope bar) red and the text white. I have done this through Interface Builder, which looks fine.

Upon building this, it appears like so (ignore the white block in tableview):
[image]

The colour should be like this, which Interface Builder produces.

[image]

The search bar is translucent. I have unchecked Translucent for the search bar.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012250/458042) answer, I have tried putting

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;
```

in my viewDidLoad and also viewWillAppear. Unfortunately neither worked.

Nothing seems to be working. I have tried this under iOS7 and iOS7.1.

Any help would be great.

Comment: These are just suggestions. I find it sometimes helps to give the search bar a background image, such as a small black rectangle. Also, here's another weird idea: try configuring the search bar in one of your search display controller's delegate methods, such as `searchDisplayController:willShowSearchResultsTableView:`.

Comment: Hi @matt, unfortunately neither of your suggested methods worked.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue as OP. Setting a background image works as a workaround, but it seems like a bug that `UISearchBar` does not respect its `translucent` property.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me to make a search bar opaque red:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(10,10), YES, 0);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0,0,10,10));
UIImage* red = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
searchBar.backgroundImage = red;
```

It works for me including in your situation, i.e. a search bar that belongs to a UISearchDisplayController with a table view controller.