# UISearchBar set translucent to NO doesn't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

(I know this may seem as duplicate, but I'm telling you all nothing I've found here worked)

I have a UITableView with a search display controller and a search bar int it, I'm trying to set the tintColor according to the company colors. But it's translucent no matter what I try.

Here is the sample code:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setTranslucent:NO];
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBarTintColor:[[ConfToolbox sharedInstance] getBarTintColor]];
```

`[[ConfToolbox sharedInstance] getBarTintColor]` returns a dark-ish blue `UIColor` .

I've looked around for an answer but nothing worked, even [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012250).

Any help would be great.

Cheers,

Ayu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted using this, just in case someone faces the same problem:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(10,10), YES, 0);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [[ConfToolbox sharedInstance] barTintColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0,0,10,10));
UIImage* coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:coloredImage forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You can set the second parameter of `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` with whatever color you want.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/translucent)

> The default value is YES. If the search bar has a custom background
>   image, the default is YES if any pixel of the image has an alpha value
>   of less than 1.0, and NO otherwise.

Since the image is made from a color with an alpha value of 1, the translucent effect is off as stated.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
    self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchBar.frame.origin.y+7, self.searchBar.frame.size.width, 30);
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search...";
    self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    self.searchBar.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth=8;
    [[NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField") appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    self.searchBar.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: This just add a sort of border around the searchbar with an opaque red color, it didn't change the search bar's tint color itself